# How to configure MemLimitOfQueryResult in DolphinDB?

Tags: configuration, config, dolphindb

I want to modify the memory limit for a query result by configuring the related parameter *MemLimitOfQueryResult*. Does anyone know where I can set this configuration? Is it involved in any file that needs to be modified? Also, do I need to restart the server after making the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to configure the memory limit:

1. **Permanent** configuration setting: specify the *MemLimitOfQueryResult* parameter in the configuration file. This method requires a server restart to take effect.
2. **Temporary** configuration setting: use `setMemLimitOfQueryResult`. This
   function allows you to change the limit during run time, without the
   need to restart the server. For more details, see [setMemLimitOfQueryResult — DolphinDB 2.0 documentation](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/CommandsReferences/s/setMemLimitOfQueryResult.html#setmemlimitofqueryresult).